# Filtering question with using Modified column when is equal to todays date - Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I'm trying to filter a list using Get Items in power automate.

Something like this: Modified eq 'TodaysDate'

But the modified field date has got a date and time and my TodaysDate filed has only date.

I have formatted TodaysDate field to show only Date as follows 'YYYY-MM-dd'

How can I filter the list by using Modified date without time with my TodayDate?

Comment: Did you try using [formatDateTime() function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatdatetime) in power automate expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint works with dates in this format.

[image]

So you want to format today's date (at midnight) using that format. Add an Initialize variable action to your flow and set its value to the expression:

`concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'T00:00:00.000Z')`

Then in the Get items action, you can do a Filter Query to get items where Modified in greater or equal to the value of the variable you created above.

`Modified ge datetime'@{variables('Today')}'`

[image: Flow actions]

Comment: Thanks Rob.
Will give this a shot.Hope it will match only the date time as i was using only the equal sign